# Libsodium-net - Unable to load DLL 'libsodium.dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, asp.net-web-api2, libsodium

I installed Libsodium-net through NuGet and am able to include Sodium in my classes, but when I try to run it, I get

An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Sodium.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'libsodium.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I am just trying to run the sample code from the gitbooks documentation
https://bitbeans.gitbooks.io/libsodium-net/content/password_hashing/index.html

```
const string PASSWORD = "Correct Horse Battery Staple";
const string SALT = "qa~t](84z<1t<1oz:ik.@IRNyhG=8q(o";
const long OUTPUT_LENGTH = 512;

//this will produce a 512 byte hash
var hash = PasswordHash.ScryptHashBinary(PASSWORD, SALT,      PasswordHash.Strength.Medium, OUTPUT_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it using [Jørn Wildt's answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275944/how-to-include-libsodium-net-on-asp-net).

> It turns out that ASP.NET doesn't make shadow copies of unmanaged DLLs such as libsodium.dll and libsodium-64.dll.
>
> Sodium.dll (the managed code) tries to load the DLLs from either the same directory as the shadow copy of Sodium.dll (which is not going to work) - or some where in the PATH environment variable's directories.
>
> My solution was to add the AppDomain \Bin directory to the path before calling any Sodium code:
>
> ```
> string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
> string binDir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Bin");
> Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path + ";" + binDir);
> ```

As Reuben commented on the answer; I added the above code in my `Application_Start` method of my `Global.asax`.

Answer (score 14):

I got this one as well. First part of the solution was to do as @NiklasEkman did, adding directory to PATH variable.

But, I got the exact same error when deployed to our QA environment. After spending hours messing with permissions, trying to figure out if the dlls are in the right directory, and similar I ran into this post:
https://mspcontrol.org/forums/topic/add-user-error-unable-to-load-dll-libsodium-64-dll/#post-4765

> You have to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (13 Mb)
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

In the end that solved the issue for me.

Comment: A couple things that snagged me: ... 1) You have to install the same target of the Visual C++ Redistributable as your process, either x64 or x86. Note that x86 is required if you are running in an ASP.NET application pool with the "Enable 32-bit applications" option turned on.... and 2) You need to restart IIS (or maybe just your app pool) after installing the redistributable.

Comment: Also, since this library may well require installation of a separate dependency (i.e. not a normal XCOPY deployment), I think it's fair to say that it may be more practical to just copy libsodium.dll and libsodium-64.dll to the C:\Windows\System32 or C:\Windows\SysWOW64 directories rather than messing with the PATH environment variable. This will depend on your specific deployment requirements, but for me, it was the best option.

Comment: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 replaced the 2015 version. I guess everything is included, but this solution does not work for me.