# Libsodium exception method not found C#

Tags: c#, libsodium

I am trying to build simple console application for encryption and decryption in C# using libsodium. I have installed libsodium-net I am using visual studio 2019 and have installed Visual studio 2015-2019 redistributable.
The build is succeeding but when i am trying to run its throwing an exception:

```
**System.TypeInitializationException**: 'The type initializer for 'Sodium.SodiumCore' threw an exception.'
Inner Exception
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY1J2.png)
I have tried the solution listed here:
[Libsodium-net - Unable to load DLL 'libsodium.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347620/libsodium-net-unable-to-load-dll-libsodium-dll/45078280#45078280)

But it didn't solve my problem.
When I try to reinstall visual studio 2015 redistributable , it says setup failed because another version is already installed on the system.[Installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f61R.png)

Comment: How are you consuming the method that is missing? Where is the code that you are using that compiled fine but throws exception on runtime?

Comment: If you want a *simple* application, why not use the built in encryption APIs? Libsodium-net is a .net wrapper around around a native library, and these are common source of problems. To start with, you usually can no longer be platform independent.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use `.net framework` library from `.net core` or `.net`. If you really need to use this version of library then target `net48`/`net461` framework. If you can use newer version, then try to find netcore compatible version