# Service Fabric Deployment Error: "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies"

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm getting the error `"Could not load file or assembly {project dll} or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found"` when attempting to publish a service fabric application to a cluster.

This application publishes to the local cluster without any problem, and runs exactly as expected. However, when I attempt to publish the application to the cluster, it fails, stating that a project dll cannot be found.

The missing dll is in the list of dlls that get packaged with the application, and all of its dependencies are non-local (system.dll, system.net.dll, etc.). The project is built for x64 to run with Service Fabric.

Comment: Sounds vaguely similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383411/libsodium-64-dll-not-found-in-production-azure-service-fabric-cluster

Comment: And check that it is built against correct .Net Framework version.

Comment: All built against .Net 4.5.2, I checked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383411/libsodium-64-dll-not-found-in-production-azure-service-fabric-cluster worked after restarting the machines after the installation, also packaged a release build to keep debug dlls out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383411/libsodium-64-dll-not-found-in-production-azure-service-fabric-cluster) worked after restarting the machines after the installation. I also packaged a release build to keep debug dlls out.