# Azure App Service hits the entry-points of references before running Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, dll

EDIT: I was able to reproduce this behavior on my local computer by debugging using IIS not IIS Express, and I was able to solve it by setting my IIS App Pool to `Allow 32-bit Applications'; My Azure website is using 32-bit platform, I don't know what else I can do up there. It does not look like Azure is a good fit for my application.

I have a ASP.NET MVC App that references a Managed C++ dll which invokes a Native C++ DLL (Yes that same scenario [I asked a different question about already](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8v0d4il640d1dei/TestMvcService%201.zip?dl=0)).

When I first ran the app, I got the error that that Native dll was not found because it wasn't part of the Shadow Copy. So I learned that the Managed C++ dll that is referencing the Native DLL needs to use a linker option called `Delay Loading` so my MVC app's `Application_Start` runs before the dependency is resolved, I used `Application_Start` to set the `PATH` environment variable and it worked great.

The problem is, I couldn't get it to work on Azure App Service. I continue to see the dependency resolving behavior running first. I added a test line to throw a test exception on `Application_Start` but I continue to see the 'Could not load assembly' error. Why is Azure different?

[Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8v0d4il640d1dei/TestMvcService%201.zip?dl=0) to download the test solution
[Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zki3phpxjau2b37/amzinet.zip?dl=0) to download the code for Managed C++ DLL with Delay Loading enabled

Comment: People shouldn't have to click to download any solution or code. How about editing your question to just include the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Native DLL dependencies with ASP.NET MVC Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740090/native-dll-dependencies-with-asp-net-mvc-projects)